# Mute/ Unmute microphone in calls via SIP javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, microphone, mute

I'm new in javascript, and I'm tring to make call via sip.

I wanna add mute button to my application, but I want it to mute **my** microphone. I mean, I don't want to mute my audio so I won't here the other side. I want the exact opposite-the other side to not hear me.

here is my html code:

```
<body onload="start()">
  <audio id="remoteAudio"></audio>
  <speaker></speaker>
  <!-- mute -->
  <button class="Rtable-cell numberBtn mute-btn" onclick="mute()">
    <img src="//webrtc.phone.do/call/getMuteImg"/>
  </button>
</body>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
function createSimple(callerURI, displayName, remoteVideoElement) {
var configuration = {
    aor,
    media: {
        remote: {
            audio: remoteVideoElement,
        },
    },
    ua: {
        traceSip: true,
        uri: aor,
        displayName: displayName,
        userAgentString: 'SIP-0.20.0.js',
        },
    };
return new SIP.Web.SimpleUser('wss://webrtc01.phone.do:443', configuration);
}


function start() {
    remoteVideoElement = document.getElementById('remoteAudio');
    remoteVideoElement.volume = 0.2;
    simple = createSimple(aor, fromName, remoteVideoElement);
    simple.connect();
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
function setStream(stream) {
    myStream = stream;
}


var myStream;
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, setStream, function () { alert('failed') });

function mute() {
    myStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = !(myStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled);
    getAudioTracks().foreach(track=>{track.stop();})

}
```

and this:

```
function mute() {
    remoteVideoElement.muted=true;
}
```

but it all mute only my audio. that, as I explained, is not what I want.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using hold instead of mute? There's option of hold the call in SIP.
Just asking. If you have not tried this already.